# Dual AFCI/GFCI breaker trip randomly

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have 3 dual AFCI/GFCI breakers in my panel and they are tripping randomly.

For example, i’ll turn the breakers on and all will be well. Then 2 days later they’ll trip. Or 12 hours later. Or a week later! It’s always different, best it’s usually within 2 days.

This last time, ALL THREE of the dual breakers flipped.

Any ideas what could be going on here? None of the circuits are under any real stress or overload. They each have some lights and outlets, and that’s about it.

Comment: Is this new problem?  How long were the breakers in before they started tripping?  Anything like vacuums/motors plugged in?  Do the breakers have lights that flash, maybe narrowing down the problem?

Comment: Do the breakers provide a method for indicating whether it is an arcing, ground fault or overload trip?  If so can you provide a readout?  Are they Eaton which also detect overvoltage?

Comment: Since they are `AFCI/GFCI ` it could be either or. Tell us, are you plugging in something, or turning something on.

Comment: @crip659 Nothing new is being plugged in. Only thing plugged into those outlets are stationary things like wifi, tv, and a few lamps. There is a power strip plugged in too.

Comment: @Ruskes Nothing new is being plugged in. That’s the weird part. Same things are plugged in all the time. And sometimes it’ll trip ALL the afci/gfci breakers on other circuits.

Comment: @JeffGeorge -- what make/model are these breakers?

Comment: Do they trip if you hit the front of the (closed) breaker panel with a palm? I'm wondering if you have a loose neutral somewhere in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

A very common reason for "random" AFCI/GFCI breaker tripping is the connection of neutral ("white") wires from different circuits at some point beyond the breaker panel.
E.g., some unknowledgeable person has mistakenly connected together all the white wires in some switch box somewhere. Detection of this problem would require de-energizing the breaker panel, disconnecting all the neutral wires, and checking for cross-connections with an ohmmeter or some such. And then hunting down the physical location(s) of such cross-connections.